# Pass a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, function

Quick probably obvious question.

If I have:

```
void print(string input)
{
  cout << input << endl;
}
```

How do I call it like so:

```
print("Yo!");
```

It complains that I'm passing in char *, instead of std::string. Is there a way to typecast it, in the call? Instead of:

```
string send = "Yo!";
print(send);
```

Comment: Josh, what compiler are you using? When I compile with "g++ -Wall -pedantic xx.cc", the above code works perfectly well for me.

Comment: Casting should not be necessary.  What compiler are you using?  What, exactly, does the error say?  And could you show your full source code?

Comment: Crap. It was breaking on my work machine, which is Ubuntu 10, using g++, with no -Wall, no -pedantic. I just tried on my OSX machine at home, and it works fine, both in a class construct (as it was breaking at work), and in a regular function.

Comment: Works fine for me for both g++ 4.5.0 in MinGW and g++ 4.2.4 in Ubuntu 8.04. No compiler options at all.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can write your function to take a `const std::string&`:

```
void print(const std::string& input)
{
    cout << input << endl;
}
```

or a `const char*`:

```
void print(const char* input)
{
    cout << input << endl;
}
```

Both ways allow you to call it like this:

```
print("Hello World!\n"); // A temporary is made
std::string someString = //...
print(someString); // No temporary is made
```

The second version does require `c_str()` to be called for `std::string`s:

```
print("Hello World!\n"); // No temporary is made
std::string someString = //...
print(someString.c_str()); // No temporary is made
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether the parameter is `std::string` or `const std::string&`.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to call print("yo!") since there is a constructor for std::string which takes a const char*.  These single argument constructors define implicit conversions from their aguments to their class type (unless the constructor is declared explicit which is not the case for std::string).  Have you actually tried to compile this code?

```
void print(std::string input)
{
    cout << input << endl;
} 
int main()
{
    print("yo");
}
```

It compiles fine for me in GCC.  However, if you declared print like this `void print(std::string& input)` then it would fail to compile since you can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary (the string would be a temporary constructed from "yo")

Answer (score 6):

Well, `std::string` is a class, `const char *` is a pointer. Those are two different things. It's easy to get from `string` to a pointer (since it typically contains one that it can just return), but for the other way, you need to create an object of type `std::string`.

My recommendation: Functions that take constant strings and don't modify them should always take `const char *` as an argument. That way, they will always work - with string literals as well as with `std::string` (via an implicit `c_str()`).

Comment: If I pass them as const char *, will I be able to use them in the member initialization list? Right now I'm passing strings to a construct, and initializing them via that.

Comment: I don't think that there exists an implicit call to c_str(). I think you would have to make the call explicitly.

Comment: @Rob Adams, as in: string s = "something"; func(s.c_str()); Right? It's explicit because it has the be instantiated as a variable, s? (Not sarcasm, serious question.)

Comment: @Josh, yes that code snippet is what i meant. It is explicit because you have to specify ".c_str()" -- it won't happen magically behind the scenes.

Comment: Sigh, I've seen too many string class implementations these days. Some have a `operator const char*() const` overload that basically returns the `c_str()`, but you're right, std::string itself doesn't have that.

Comment: The object creation is the creation of the parameter, it doesn't need to be constructed explicitly by the caller. (As an aside, by now the recommendation in the second half may be out-dated.)

Answer (score 4):

```
print(string ("Yo!"));
```

You need to make a (temporary) `std::string` object out of it.

Comment: This wasn't necessary even if 2010. The original code should work as is.

Answer (score 4):

For easy stuff like printing, you can define a sort of function in your preprocessors like:

```
#define print(x) cout << x << endl
```

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way would be to call the function like this

```
print(string("Yo!"));
```

Comment: This wasn't necessary even if 2010. The original code should work as is.

Answer (score 3):

Make it so that your function accepts a `const std::string&` instead of by-value. Not only does this avoid the copy and is therefore *always* preferable when accepting strings into functions, but it also enables the compiler to construct a temporary `std::string` from the `char[]` that you're giving it. :)

Comment: A temporary doesn't need to be constructed, the parameter can be directly constructed from the argument. This should have been true in 2011 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it as a `const char *`.

`print((const char *)"Yo!")` will work fine.

Comment: This wasn't necessary. The original code should work as is.